# Запуск deflate из программы

Tags: c#

Необходимо запустить программу deflate.exe и передать файл, который нужно сжать и имя нового файла.

> C:\Users>C:...\deflate.exe < C:...\file.bin > C:...\arph.z

Файл для сжатия должен быть в "<>".
Все срабатывает верно.
Но мне необходимо запустить deflate из другой программы и тут я столкнулся с проблемой.

Код программы:

```
Process pr = new Process();

pr.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\...\deflate.exe";
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = @"<C:\...\file.bin> C:\...\arph.z";

pr.Start();
pr.WaitForExit()
```

Данная программа не срабатывает. Открывается консоль основного .exe и окно deflate.exe (если не указывать pr.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true и так далее).
Есть какие-нибудь соображения или замечания по этому поводу?

Comment: Файл для сжатия должен быть в "<>" - на основании чего сделан такой вывод?

Comment: Это, я бы сказал, исходные данные.

Comment: Крайне странные исходные данные...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<> и имена файлов - это не параметры deflate.exe. Это инструкции для командного процессора по перенаправлению ввода-вывода. Вы запускаете deflate.exe напрямую - перенаправление не работает. Вам нужно запускать сам командный процессор - `cmd` с параметром `/c`, который выполняет остаток строки как команду

```
Process pr= new Process();
pr.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp\def";
pr.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C deflate.exe < .... > ....";
pr.Start();
```

А еще лучше - не заморачиватся со сжатием через deflate.exe, а использовать стандартный `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream`:

```
using (var output = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\def\sample.txt.z"))
{
    using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\def\sample.txt"))
        {
            input.CopyTo(deflateStream);
        }
    }
}
```